# How to integrate SQL Server Reporting Services with my Application?

Tags: c#, sql-server, reporting-services

I generated a report using SQL Server Reporting Services. But I want to include that report in my project. How to do it? How to add that report which was generated by BI development studio to my solution in a C# windows application?

Comment: Read this article for [how to Integrate Reporting Services to your application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa964126%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)

Comment: Take a look at this link on how to integrate the reporting services into your project.. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa964126(v=sql.90).aspx http://www.codeproject.com/KB/reporting-services/ReportViewer2005.aspx